# Can Bulgaria stamp my Schengen visa for entry point?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit-visas

I have a **single-entry** Schengen visa,  obtained for travel to Italy. I reside in Dubai. I would like to enter Italy via a flight to Bulgaria. That is, I will fly from Dubai to Bulgaria, stay there for one day and then fly ahead to Italy.

But I want Italy to be my first point of entry to Schengen area. Now since Bulgaria isn't a Schengen country, they will not stamp my Schengen visa right? **Will Italy be my first point of entry to Schengen area?**

Answer (score 6):

Correct. The fact that Bulgaria allows holders of Schengen visas to enter Bulgaria does not affect the validity of the Schengen visa for actually entering the Schengen area.

Your single entry will be used only when you actually enter the territory of the Schengen Area, which does not include Bulgaria.

(And even if the Bulgarian border guards should happen to place a stamp covering the visa, they're not actually empowered to cancel it, so the stamp would be a nullity as far as the validity of the visa is concerned).